# How do I use a microphone in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, voice-chat

I have searched the game menus and cannot find how to enable my headset microphone. Is this possible in Diablo 3? What are the alternatives? Are there external programs used for this?

Comment: Related: [PC voice chat software](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/pc-voice-chat-software)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NO, there is no Voice-chat (yet) in Diablo3**

> "There is no built in voice chat, at least not for ship," Bashiok
>   said. "If we try voice chat in another game we want to make sure its
>   worth using."

Sources [G4](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/720619/diablo-3-will-only-support-4-player-co-op-and-wont-have-in-game-voice-chat-community-manager-bashiok-explains-why/) [Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/Bashiok/statuses/166780531621634050)

You can talk with your friends using a third party technology such as:

> 1. [Ventrilo](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/720619/diablo-3-will-only-support-4-player-co-op-and-wont-have-in-game-voice-chat-community-manager-bashiok-explains-why/) for its ease in finding and buying a hosted Vent server.
> 2. [Team Speak](https://twitter.com/#!/Bashiok/statuses/166780531621634050), the most common Vent alternative.
> 3. [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/home) is popular because many gamers have it already and no server is needed.
> 4. [XFire](http://www.xfire.com/) for its integrated IM and social networking platform.
> 5. [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) because it is free and open source.

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2833/12936)

Comment: Skype typically has the best audio quality and is foolproof as you don't have to rely on the server administrator to know what they're doing (Vent, TS, Mumble).  This goes beyond the codec/bandwidth; I've been on some Vent servers with comparable "raw" quality, but Skype is also intelligent enough to make sure everyone's levels are close by amplifying/quieting as needed (you can do this in other VoIP programs but it's manual).  The drawbacks of Skype are the 8-person call limit (not really relevant here) and the call seems to be "hosted" by the first person to call so can eat some bandwidth.

Comment: Oh, and Skype's interface kinda sucks.

Comment: we can build an entire post about each characteristic of each VoIP listed. in this case, is better let others check it by them-self.

Comment: I made a 5 hour skype call on the weekend and found it to be great!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Steam (if you have it). Most gamers have a Steam account, I've found, and it's actually pretty decent voice chat quality.

Answer (score 3):

Diablo 3 does not support in game voice chat.

Popular solutions include: Mumble, Ventrillo, Skype, and Teamspeak.

All the solutions above sans Skype require a central server for you and your friends to connect to. These typically cost money(there are some free servers that allow you to create a channel for your group). These services offer more control as well as persistence(rather than needing to setup a new call in Skype each time).

Skype is a free solution, however, and for smaller groups works perfectly fine.

Note: all of the services I listed are free if you don't plan on hosting a server and just joining others.

Comment: Would be good a question comparing all those, but it's too much subjective. In my opinion Ventrilo is the best. I don't like Skype at all.

Comment: @MichelAyres I'm rather fond of Mumble myself, but I'm not really familiar enough with all of them to make a point by point comparison.

Comment: Ummm...why not use Steam? Most gamers have that...